# Trying to trigger a minimal rebuild with CMake and set_source_files_properties

Tags: cmake

I've got my problem isolated to a very small two-sources project here: https://github.com/ennorehling/versioning/tree/v0.1

What I am trying to do is to not have a hard-coded version number in version.c, but to feed the version number into my build process from an external variable. See s/build for my build process: If $VERSION is defined, I want that to be the version number that the program prints. I achieve this by executing the command VERSION=1.2 s/build form the shell (or, if VERSION is undefined, by using the most recent tag from git).

The problem with this is that I run `cmake .. -DVERSION=$VERSION` every time I build, and that re-creates the Makefile, which causes a full rebuild. I would like to only rebuild version.o, since it is the only source file that depends on the version number. Building main.o (and in a real project, every other object, too) is unnecessary. I originally used add_definitions, which would add the -D compile switch to every source, and I thought set_source_files_properties was how I would be able to solve this, but since both object files are generated out of the same generated Makefile in build/CMakeFiles/version.dir/build.make, which gets touched by the cmake process. It seems that make errs on the safe side and just rebuilds everything?

Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree entirely, and just haven't found the correct CMake command for this, I don't know. Maybe there are other, proven ways to achieve what I'm trying to do? At this point, I've spent so much time on this, I'm not ashamed to ask for help.

Comment: does this also happen, if you parse in the actual string instead of the environment variable?

Comment: Sometimes all you have to do is explain your problem to somebody, and suddenly your brain comes up with a solution. I'm answering my own question.

Comment: The code should be **in the question itself**, not linked. As you have so small files, I see no reason to not include them into the question. As for the problem, there was a number of questions on SO which tends to regenerate version file at **build stage**, not by passing it into `cmake`. Is this approach is applicable for you?

Comment: Didn't know about that rule, but I see how it prevents link-rot and is probably a good one. I felt that including 30-40 lines of code was going to make this harder to read, and having a github project anyone can clone was more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to work around this. The root problem here is that CMake create a Makefile for each library or executable target, and since my code only has one target, it was touching that Makefile every time. So the answer is to make a library target for version.c!

```
add_library(version OBJECT version.c)
add_executable(hello main.c $<TARGET_OBJECTS:version>)
```

this creates separate files in build/CMakeFiles/version.dir and build/CMakeFiles/hello.dir, and changes to the VERSION number only affect one of them, and the single target in it. The executable's dependencies are unchanged and don't get rebuilt, and only the linker step is executed, cutting down my build times as desired.

It's a bit clunky, but it works for me. New version of the project is here:
https://github.com/ennorehling/versioning/tree/v1.0

Edit: it turns out that Ubuntu Precise doesn't have CMake 2.8.8 yet, and the OBJECT option to add_library needs it. So instead, I have to actually create a library from that single object file and link it, like this:

```
add_library(version version.c)
add_executable(hello main.c)
target_link_libraries(hello version)
```

Not a huge deal, but a little annoying.

Comment: i seems add_library( ... OBJECT ...) is a CMake 2.8.8 feature, and Ubuntu Precise (our CI builder) only has 2.8.7. Sigh.

Comment: Upgrading to a newer CMake may very well be worth the effort; there are lots and lots of nice features and bugfixes in newer CMakes.

Comment: Sadly, I'm limited to what's in Ubuntu Precise, because that's what Travis CI uses. Asking them to upgrade is more hassle than it's worth as long as I don't absolutely need one of those features or bugfixes. They'll eventually upgrade their docker images, I'm sure. I can wait.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't need to reconfigure every time. Once the make/build environment is written the problem can be reduced to a simple "has the file changed" problem that is checked by `make` itself.

So I probably would just generate the `version.c` inside your build script (and add this file to your `.gitignore` or alternatively directly generate it into the `build` directory):

**s/build**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$VERSION" ]; then
    VERSION=$(git describe --tags --match "v*.*")
    if [ -z "$VERSION" ]; then
        VERSION=1.0.0
    fi
fi

echo "const char *version(void) { return \"${VERSION}\"; }" > version.c~
if cmake -E compare_files version.c~ version.c 
then
    cmake -E remove version.c~
else
    cmake -E rename version.c~ version.c
fi        

if ! [ -d build ]; then
    cmake -E make_directory build
    cmake -H. -Bbuild
fi
cmake --build build
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(version C)

add_executable(version version.c main.c)
```

**version.c**

```c
const char *version(void) { return "1.0.0"; }
```

**main.c**

```c
#include "stdio.h"

const char *version(void);

void main(void) {
    puts(version());
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't think we can completely get rid of the version.c file, because of our Visual Studio build (which does not care that the version number is correct, and doesn't use a bash script to run git), but there's definitely stuff here that I should be able to use. I didn't know about cmake -E, for example. Thanks!

Comment: @Enno You're welcome. One thing you can also do, is to translate the `version.c` creation into a CMake script you can call with `cmake -P`. The advantage would be that those scripts are platform independent and CMake is anyway available on the host system. In my environment I'm using such a script as a pre-link step because we add user information and time-stamps to every application version we build.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the CMake `Unix Makefile` generator. I tried your (original) code example using the `Ninja` generator, and `ninja` manages to avoid rebuilding `main.c` if you only change the version number.

Comment: I've heard good things about ninja, but never looked into it closely. Makefiles are just the most universal building block, so I didn't feel a strong urge to make changes. It's possile that the ninja generator structures its output differently, and does not stumble over the same issues as the Makefile generator (I wouldn't go so far as to call this a bug, just an implementation detail). But thanks for checking!